# Apache Nifi - `ConvertJSONToSQL` possible duplicates

Tags: apache-nifi

Please find below my flow,

`ExecuteSQL` -> `SplitAvro` -> `ConvertAvroToJSON` -> `ConvertJSONToSql` -> `PutSQL`

[image: My Flow On Nifi]

Note the `ConvertJSONToSQL` processor which receives **5403** and send **10804**. Could someone please explain what is happening here? I'm expecting to see the IN and OUT counts are same just like the `CovertAvroToJSON` processor. This increased number will have direct impact on my final output table where i can see duplicates for all the records.

`ConvertJSONToSQL` processor injecting possible duplicate SQL insert statements?

**UPDATE 2/28** 
I have taken out the `SplitAvro` processor and the records are populated without the duplicates!!!! Please find below the flow,

`ExecuteSQL` -> `ConvertAvroToJSON` -> `ConvertJSONToSql` -> `PutSQL`

I haven't figured out the exact problem though!

Comment: Please provide more details to help us solve your issue. If you can, export the flow as a template and post it to https://gist.github.com.

Comment: @Andy, Sorry, i noticed the template contains confidential information about the database i was connecting to. So, shall i remove those information and share you the xml? Will that be helpful?

Comment: NiFi template exports do not contain any "sensitive" values (I don't mean the logical definition, which is ultimately determined by you in this case, but processor properties marked as *sensitive* (i.e. DB passwords, etc.) are not exported).

Comment: Okay. I think i'm trying to do something wrong to export. Could you please explain me to how to export the flow?

Comment: See [Creating a Template](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Create_Template) and [Exporting a Template](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Export_Template) in the NiFi User Guide for instructions on each of these actions.

Comment: here you go https://gist.github.com/Ponsivakumar/c9be874830a883dfe180fe11a223871a . hopefully this is useful for you

Comment: Usually you debug these issues by using a `LogAttribute` processor and examining the queue to determine why there are more flowfiles than expected (obviously try for smaller scale to debug).

Comment: okay. thank you for the suggestion. I haven't used `LogAttribute` before. I will use `LogAttribute` to understand more about the flowfiles

Comment: @Andy, taking out the `SplitAvro` results in no duplicates. Not sure how this is helping me!

Comment: Would have to compare the output of the SplitAvro to the incoming data. If SplitAvro was acting weird and generating some records which converted 1:1 to JSON but the JSON records were corrupted in some way and the conversion from JSON to SQL duplicated, it could result in the scenario you saw above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible for your flow/data that even after the SplitAvro and ConvertAvroToJSON, the flow file(s) contain JSON arrays? According to the documentation, "If the input is an array of JSON elements, each element in the array is output as a separate FlowFile to the 'sql' relationship".

Perhaps try ConvertAvroToJSON -> SplitJSON rather than SplitAvro -> ConvertAvroToJSON. If you are still getting arrays at the "top level", then ConvertJsonToSQL will still create one flow file for each element in the array. In that case you may need another SplitAvro or (alternatively) a SplitJson.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have taken out `SplitAvro` processor out of my original flow and everything is working fine. It is interesting that how this is making the different. My corrected/updated flow is `ExecuteSQL` -> `ConvertAvroToJSON` -> `ConvertJSONToSql` -> `PutSQL`. This loads the sink database without any duplicate records.

Comment: You should be able to replace all of that with `ExecuteSQL` -> `PutDatabaseRecord`, the latter processor handles the SQL generation and execution.